# ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey on has_many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm running into the following error when trying to destroy a Project that has many Users through ProjectUser model.

Using pgsql, rails 6.0.3, ruby 2.7...

I'm not sure what I'm missing in this case. Can somebody shed some light, please?

**This is the complete error:**

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey in ProjectsController#destroy

PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: update or delete on table "projects" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_1bf16ed5d0" on table "project_users" DETAIL: Key (id)=(8) is still referenced from table "project_users".
```

**Here are my model, controllers, and schema:**

projects_controller.rb

```
def destroy
  @project.destroy
  redirect_to projects_url, notice: 'Project was successfully destroyed.'
end
```

project.rb

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_users
  has_many :users, through: :project_users
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_users
  has_many :projects, through: :project_users
end
```

project_user.rb

```
class ProjectUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "project_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.bigint "project_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["project_id"], name: "index_project_users_on_project_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_project_users_on_user_id"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must destroy first every project user associated to that project, and then destroy the project.

Or you can modify your `has_many` relationship and specify that when destroying a project, every related record (not only project_users, all of them) are destroyed as well:

```
has_many :project_users, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Would adding `dependent: :destroy` on the `has_many :project_users` association do any harm to the User or Project table data?

Comment: It'll only destroy related `project_users`, if `project_users` has also defined `dependent: :destroy` relationships then it'll delete every related record for.